# jquery 1.4.2 and chrome.. detecting a check box is checked....How?

Tags: jquery, asp.net-mvc-3, razor, checkbox, jquery-1.4

So for reasons beyond my control, I'm using jquery 1.4.2 and chrome..

I'm having a ludicrous amount of trouble trying to get detecting a check box is checked....working...

Here is what I have...

HTMl generated by asp.net Mvc3

```
<input type="checkbox" name="criteriaVm.WasApproved" id="criteriaVm.WasApproved">
```

Various versions I've tried

```
            var ob = $("#criteriaVm.WasApproved");// is valid
            var chk = ob.attr('checked'); // undefined
            chk = ob.prop('checked');//crash
            chk = ob.get(0).checked;//crash
            chk = ob.get(0).is(":checked");//crash
            chk = ob.is(":checked");//undefined
            chk = ob.is(":checked");// always returns false
```

I've tried others before I started keeping track to make sure I wasn't just going in circles...

Does anyone know what version works on the old school jquery i'm, stuck with?

Comment: Why the down vote with no feedback as to why?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`var ob = $("#criteriaVm.WasApproved")` is does not select the element with `id="criteriaVm.WasApproved"` (and `ob.length;` returns `0`).

It selects an element with `id="criteriaVm"` that has a class name `class="WasApproved"` (which does not exist)

Having a `.`, `[` or `]` in an `id` attribute will always cause problems with jquery selectors, which is why the `HtmlHelper` methods replace those characters with an `_` (underscore) when generating the `id` attribute.

Change your `id` attribute to `id="criteriaVm_WasApproved"` (or anything you like that does not contain invalid characters) and use

```
<input type="checkbox" name="criteriaVm.WasApproved" id="criteriaVm_WasApproved">

var ob = $("#criteriaVm_WasApproved");
ob.length; // now return 1
var chk = ob.is(':checked'); // or ob.prop('checked'); etc
```

Comment: Have not verified, but makes perfect sense, so I marked it. I'd already recoded it to use a dropdown :D